# Replacing text in between certain symbols

Tags: java, regex, replace

I am given a string like this:
CSF@asomedatahere@iiwin@hnotwhatIwant

And I want to replace the string that is present BETWEEN @i and @h (h could be any character) . This is what I have so far and I feel that I am close, however, there may not always be a @CHAR after this @idata pattern.

```
 (?<=@i)(.*)(?=@.*)
```

I would like it to work for that optionally not being there. As it can be seen in the link below it works for the first case not the second. I tried adding a '?' at the end to make the last part optional but that makes it not work for the first case.

Here is a link that will show you actively what is not working: http://fiddle.re/vtvmc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand the look-ahead to use the end of the input as well:

```
(?<=@i)(.*?)(?=@.*|$)
```

This would match

- `iwin@hnotwhatIwant` in `CSF@asomedatahere@iiwin@hnotwhatIwant`
- `iwin@h` in `CSF@asomedatahere@iiwin@h`
- `iwin` in `CSF@asomedatahere@iiwin`.

Comment: Thank you! Thought I tried something like that, but I probably changed other things as well.